# Error running new tornadoFX app with openJdk 14.0.1

Tags: java, kotlin, javafx, tornadofx

I'm geting this error every time I try to run my app

```
Kotlin: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class tornadofx.UIComponent, unresolved supertypes: javafx.event.EventTarget
    class tornadofx.App, unresolved supertypes: javafx.application.Application
```

I installed the openjdk and openjfx following this guide https://developer.tizen.org/development/articles/openjdk-and-openjfx-installation-guide

My os is Windows 10, I'm using intellij IDEA community and my Kotlin plugin version is 1.4.10